Who has created the various Laws of Nature which govern the functioning of this universe?
Namasthe,
I have a question.
There are many divine laws which govern the functioning of the universe, such as law of karma, or any other laws of Nature.
Who is creator of such laws?
As per my knowledge Sages, rishis , munis, Englightened beings have written many scriptures such as Vedas, Purans itihasas, Smritis , Sutras etc.
So sages, Rishi , Munis , enlightenment beings create the laws of Nature ?? or Ishvara created the laws of nature but sages are just handing down the laws which is created by God and documenting in scriptures?? Or any other external entity is creator of laws of nature such as devtas or Celestial beings?
Who is responsible for creating the Various Laws of nature which govern the functioning of universe (or prakiriti)?
Is it God(Ishvara) or any other entity?
You may say Laws of Nature have existed since eternity . But laws of nature or laws of Karma come into existence only when there is a Universe as without a universe, there is no point in laws  And for Universe to exist, there needs to be a creator and God(Ishvara or saguna brahman) is responsible for creation of universe as per Vedanta school. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
So is God(Ishvara ) responsible for creation of Laws of Nature which govern the functioning of cosmos?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I) Your first question who created Law of Karma?
Brahma-Sutra[1.1.1] says:
अथातो ब्रह्मजिज्ञासा ॥१॥
Hence [is to be undertaken] thereafter an inquiry of brahman [a wish to know brahman]. ॥1॥

The word atah(अतः) is used in the sense of "sequence" and not "commencement" because brahmajijñāsā(ब्रह्मजिज्ञासा) is not a thing that can be commenced because  Brahman is anādhi.
The word atha(अथ/now) in the Sutra is not used to introduce a new subject that is going to be taken up, as used in other places, e-g in the beginning of the Yoga-Sutras (अथ योगानुशासनम् ॥१.१॥) or the Purva Mimamsa-Sutras (अथातो धर्म​जिज्ञासा ॥१॥). The word atha(अथ/now) has occasioned different interpretations as follows:

Ramanuja and Nimbarka argue that it refers to the position of
"knowledge of Brahman" as coming "after the knowledge of karman and
its fruits".
Shankara takes it as referencing sādhana chatushtayam (the
acquisition of the four requisite qualities) and
Vallabha disagrees the needs for four qualities to enquire about
Brahman, and interprets 'atha' as merely the beginning of a new
topic.

The word Karma(कर्म॒) appears in Rig Veda [3.32.8]:
इन्द्र॑स्य॒ कर्म॒ सुकृ॑ता पु॒रूणि॑ व्र॒तानि॑ दे॒वा न मि॑नन्ति॒ विश्वे॑ ।
दा॒धार॒ यः पृ॑थि॒वीं द्यामु॒तेमां ज॒जान॒ सूर्य॑मु॒षसं॑ सु॒दंसा॑: ॥ ८ ॥

All the gods cannot detract from the many glorious exploits, and pious
works of Indra; he who has upheld earth, and heaven, and the
firmament, and who, the performer of great deeds, has engendered the
sun and the dawn.

Yājñavalkya says in Brihadaranyaka upanishad [3.2.13] which belongs to Sukla Yajur Veda:
पुण्यो वै पुण्येन कर्मणा भवति, पापः पापेनेति 

(Therefore) one indeed becomes good through good work and evil through
evil work.

In Brihadaranyaka upanishad [4.4.5] Yājñavalkya says about karma which results from desire as given below:
यथाकारी यथाचारी तथा भवति—साधुकारी साधुर्भवति, पापकारी पापो भवति;
पुण्यः पुण्येन कर्मणा भवति, पापः पापेन । अथो खल्वाहुः काममय एवायं
पुरुष इति; स यथाकामो भवति तत्क्रतुर्भवति, यत्क्रतुर्भवति तत्कर्म
कुरुते, यत्कर्म कुरुते तदभिसंपद्यते ॥ ५ ॥

What one becomes is dependent upon one's actions, and attitudes. The
doer of good deeds becomes good, the doer of evil deeds becomes evil.
One becomes virtuous by virtuous actions and bad by evil actions.
Others however will add that a person consists of desires. As is one’s
desire so is one’s intention; as is the intention so is the deed that
is done, and one’s deeds determine what one will become.

Beware-1: According to Vedas, Law of Karma emanates from Brahman Himself.
II) Your second question As per my knowledge Sages, rishis , munis, Englightened beings have written many scriptures such as Vedas, Purans itihasas, Smritis , Sutras etc
Brahma-Sutra[1.1.3] says:
शास्त्रयोनित्वात् ॥३॥ 
[Brahman is all-knower] because of [Its] being the source of the scriptures.॥3॥

Brahman is the yoni (i.e. material and efficient cause) of great scriptures (sāstras) like Rig-Veda etc. which are supplemented by other scriptures (Sikṣā, chandas, vyākaraṇa, nirukta, kalpa and jyotiṣa) that are themselves sources of knowledge.
Beware-2: For scriptures like Rig-Veda, possessed of all good qualtities can't possibly emerge from any source other than an all-knowing One. This proves Rishis never created Scriptures which emerged from Brahman Himself.
III) Your third and final question Who is responsible for creating the Various Laws of nature which govern the functioning of universe (or prakiriti)?
Brahma-Sutra[1.1.2] says:
जन्माद्यस्य यतः ॥२॥
That [is Brahman] from which [are derived] the birth etc. of this [universe].॥2॥

Janmādi can be split as Janma (birth) + Adi (first). The compound implies srsti, stiti and laya in that order.
That omniscient and omnipotent source must be Brahman from which occur srsti, stiti and laya of this universe that is manifested through name and form, that is associated with diverse agents and experiences, that provides the support for actions and results, having well-regulated space, time and causation. Thus, Brahman offers "level playing field" to Sakala Jeevarāsi (सकल जीवराशी/All Biological Species) living not only on earth but also on all abodes, without prejudice. All jivas attempt to reach God's feet (known as moksha) and all of them are governed by a common law known as Karma which causes samsāra (cycle of birth and death). "As you sow, so shall you reap," encapsulating the essence of Karma. According to Svetāsvatara upanishad [6.11] and BG [13.23], Brahman is Witness.
Beware-3: Thus, the Laws of Nature (all Sciences) governing the universe emerged from Brahman Himself.
Conclusion:
Having answered all questions in the post using comments, OP has commented further quoting Kapila Muni and Lord Krishna about working of Law of Karma. This was a clear misunderstanding on the functioning of Law of Karma with the notion that Karma works independently of Brahman. Let us understand what is witness before clearing this doubt.
According to Svetāsvatara upanishad [6.11] and BG [13.23], Brahman is Witness.

In order to understand the physical significance of the term Witness in spiritualism, let us bring out an analogy.
On a sheet of paper, you just spread some iron pieces and observe that
they remain motionless and will be so forever. However, the moment a
magnet is swayed under the sheet, the iron pieces gets life all of a
sudden and will begin to move.

The cause of this animation is simply the proximity of a magnet. Here magnet is Brahman, 'pieces of iron' is Karma and proximity of magnet is Witness.
Like 'pieces of iron' acts under the proximity of a magnet, Karma is Jada (जड/inert) or acetana(अचेतन/inanimate) as such, so it requires the presence of Brahman to act. That is why I had been kept on saying that the Brahman is Witness and Law of Karma takes care. In other words, Law of Karma will work only under the presence of Brahman and it does not mean that Brahman is acting or working directly.
I have asked OP to create a separate post for his comments deviating from the topic of post.

Sir, in point 2. It's mentioned in  https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras-nimbarka/d/doc376143.html Brahman cannot be arrived at through inference, but has the Veda for His proof. Why? “Because (Brahman has) Scripture for His source”. That means: “Scripture”, i.e. the Veda, is the “source”, the informant, the proof, with regard to whom,—that object is “Śāstra-yoni” and “Śāstra-yonitva” is the state of being “Śāstra-yoni”—on account of that, i.e.on account of having Scripture for His proof The correct conclusion is that Brahman has the Veda alone for His proof not vice versa

Note :- The above is taken from commentary posted in link. Not my words sir

Nimbarka, was a 13th century philosophe who founded the Nimbarka Sampradaya, a Hindu sect that worships the divine couple Radha and Krishna. Nimbarka's theology is known as Dvaitadvaita (aka dualistic non-dualism). Please quote anything only based on Shankara Bhasyam and no other bhasyam such as Nimbarka because it is not advaidam. Please be conscious before quoting what philosophy are you referring to!
