Manu Smriti - Are Laws of Universe created by God?
Namasthe
In Manu Smriti Manu Smriti 7.14, It is mentioned the Rod of punishment emerged from brahman.

तस्यार्थे सर्वभूतानां गोप्तारं धर्ममात्मजम् । ब्रह्मतेजोमयं दण्डमसृजत् पूर्वमीश्वरः ॥ १४ ॥
tasyārthe sarvabhūtānāṃ goptāraṃ dharmamātmajam | brahmatejomayaṃ
daṇḍamasṛjat pūrvamīśvaraḥ || 14 ||
For his sake, the Lord, at first, created Punishment, which is Law
born of the Lord Himself, an incarnation of divine glory and the
protector of all creatures.—(14).

Translation from CHAT GPT

Verse Translation:
To protect all living beings and uphold righteousness, the Supreme
Lord (Ishwara) created the rod of punishment (Danda), imbued with the
brilliance of Brahman (spiritual energy). This rod, born of Dharma
(righteousness) and His divine essence, was meant to enforce
discipline and ensure order.

Is this translation correct? The word दण्डम exact translation refers to Rod of punishment Does this mean Law of punishment ? Does rod in this context means a Law of punishment ?
This is the next verse (7.15)

तस्य सर्वाणि भूतानि स्थावराणि चराणि च ।
भयाद् भोगाय कल्पन्ते स्वधर्मात्न चलन्ति च ॥ १५ ॥
tasya sarvāṇi bhūtāni sthāvarāṇi carāṇi ca | bhayād bhogāya kalpante
svadharmātna calanti ca || 15 ||
It is through fear of him that all living beings, movable as well as
immovable, go to subserve the experiences (of men) and do not swerve
from their duties.—(15)"

Also, this section is about King and punishment

स राजा पुरुषो दण्डः स नेता शासिता च सः । चतुर्णामाश्रमाणां च धर्मस्य प्रतिभूः स्मृतः ॥ १७ ॥
sa rājā puruṣo daṇḍaḥ sa netā śāsitā ca saḥ | caturṇāmāśramāṇāṃ ca
dharmasya pratibhūḥ smṛtaḥ || 17 ||
That punishment is the ‘King’, the ‘Man’; that is the ‘Leader’ and the
‘Ruler’ and that has been declared to be the ‘surety’ for the Law of
the Four Stages.—(17)
.

I have three questions
QUESTION 1
Here It does not explicitly mention "Law of punishment", Does it mean the concept of punishment came from Lord , or does it mean Law of punishment came from Lord ? So is it just a CONCEPT or a LAW created by God?
QUESTION 2
If it's a Law, does it imply all the different various Laws of universe such as law of karma and all the different laws of universe created by God(or brahman) himself ?
QUESTION 3
This section is about King . These sloka is it only apply for King about how a King should govern his subjects or in general for every living entity (or Jiva)?
Is there any other mentioned in scriptures about it ?

Arthashastra says upāyāḥ sāmopapradānabhedadaṇḍāḥ || 2.10.47 || Meaning: Chanakya(aka Kautilya) mentioned four Upayas - Sama, Dana, Bheda and Danda, as ways to reach a solution in state politics to avoid conflicts and war situations [Arthashastra 2.10.47]. The meaning of Danda (दण्ड) is punishment, not rod.

Sir is there any scriptural references which states law of karma emerged from Brahmn?

I already answered this question. Please refer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61551/who-has-created-the-various-laws-of-nature-which-govern-the-functioning-of-this/61595#61595

According to Brahma Sutra Bhasyam of Ramanuja, the word atha (therefore) intimates that what has taken place (viz. the study of the karmakāṇḍa of the Veda) constitutes the reason (of the enquiry into Brahman). What is important is  Yājñavalkya says in Brihadaranyaka upanishad [3.2.13]: पुण्यो वै पुण्येन कर्मणा भवति, पापः पापेनेति Meaning: (Therefore) one indeed becomes good through good work and evil through evil work. Rig Veda [3.32.8] has the word Karma. There is one more mantra in Brihadaranyaka upanishad. All theses instances prove that  Law of Karma emanates from Brahman.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/origin-of-the-law-of-karma Here Keshav srinivasan states that The law of Karma is not explictly mentioned in the Samhitas of the Vedas (the part of the Vedas heard from the gods) but the earliest enunciation of the doctrine of Karma comes to us from these words of the sage Yajnavalkya, a contemporary of Janaka. Based on this would it imply Yajnavalkya created this law of karma ?

Do you mean veda was written by Yajnavalkya? If Yajnavalkya  created Law of Karma, then before he was born, was there no Law of Karma? You are no thinking @Karthik . Refer your earlier post regarding wherefrom scriptures came? I gave proof quoting Bramha sutra 1.1.1, 1.1.2 and 1.1.3. What else you want?

Okay sir I got it . Thanks but there is one small clarification. This is not related directly to the post I have commented in this thread. Brahma sutras say that Ishvara gives the fruits of karma but that clearly contradicts the fact Brahman is just a witness( BG 9.18 and Svetasvathara upanishad) and brahman is just a neutral observer (BG 9.9)

Unless you understood, the analogy of Magnet and 'Iron Pieces' it is difficult to grasp law of karma and karma palan; what is the relationship between being witness and giving karma palan? BOTH ARE SAME. Everything happening under Brahman (or Isvara). He remain neutral as witness at the same time giver of fruits of palan based on Law of Karma. He never overrides Law of Karma. Try to understand.

Sir as per BG 9.9 god's witness and neutral observer while everything happens as per law of Karma . God does not have any role at all and you had mentioned just like a sun he remains as witness. But Brahma sutras say he is the giver of fruits of karma . That means god has role to play that contradicts the fact that god has no role to play and just a neutral observer or witness right sir

WITHOUT GOD , there is NO LAW OF KARMA and  NOTHING WILL HAPPEN! Will Iron pieces dance without the influence of a magnet? I told you to understand the is analogy well!

Sorry to ask again. But In the magnet example and sun example which you had given , god is just witness and has no role to play. But as per Brahma sutras god gives the Karma palan that means god actively has role to play. Not just witness but giving Karma palan as well? As per magnet example law of karma takes care of everything and god doesn't personally involve but it contradicts Brahma sutras where god personally intervenes and gives the fruits of karma (karma-palan)

NEVER SAY GOD HAS NO ROLE TO PLAY. Will iron pieces move without a magnet? Remember karma is Jada. Karma plan is jada. Everything else is jada except Brahman and Jivas. There is a vast difference between "witness" and "no role to play". Witness means everything happening under his watch but he will never participate. Suppose some one says "I am a murder Witness" then it does not mean that the witness has murdered!  He is just witness to a murder!!

Yes I get it sir god has role to play but what I'm getting confused is, you had mentioned god doesn't intervene at all except in rare situation like Dhruva ,and  just because of mere presence of brahman the law of karma takes care. But as per Brahma sutras god intervenes and gives the Karma palan that means god decides the Karma palan which means god's intervention is there. This i was confused sir . I'm sorry if I'm bothering this was my confusion.

Here as per Brahma sutras god is participating by giving Karma palan so directly he is intervening

Lord Krishna said Karma is complex and hard to understand. If your karma permits, then God will intervene. There is no contradiction. This means God will never tamper with your sanchita karma nor prarabda karma nor agamikarma voluntarily. Where is God intervening in brahma sutra? Giving karma plan and being witness both are one and same. There is not point in discussing further on this. Please read Upanishads (10 mukya upanishad) and Vedanta very well then you will get to understand.

Okay one last question regarding this sir . Does God give the karma phala and decide next birth as told in Brahma sutras? If so, does it considered as intervening,?

If God decides everything directly then why do you need Law of Karma? Suppose your are the owner a large company. Can you run the whole company by yourself? No, you need a hierarchy of staffs who run the company and your role is to oversee it. Remember it does not mean you have no role play and you witness every activity without direct interference. The right context is Law of Karma decides next birth in the presence of Brahman as witness. At the same if you say God has given me this birth, then that is also valid as long as God is not antagonist with Law of Karma. Good Luck!

Yes. That was my actual doubt . If god decides everything , why do we need law of karma. It's not required . But in Brahma sutras they mentioned god decides everything. That contradicts with fact that god is witness and neutral observer

Please give the reference for Brahma sutras mentioning god decides everything where law of karma does not need?

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras/d/doc74952.html it's mentioned here

I have removed it sir. But i request you can u pls answer that if i create a new post for these 3 deleted questions sir @Marmayogi

Mimamsa is a non-theistic philosophy that argues that there is no need for a god or creator of the world. Mimamsa theorists believe that it is our karma that brings its rewards or retribution, not Isvara. So the Mīmāṃsā philosophy emphasizes on the karmakāṇḍa of the Veda and unfolds a philosophy to justify and to help the continuation of the vedic rites and rituals. Mimamsa also defends other metaphysical ideas, such as the reality of the physical world and the immortality of the soul. [Cont...]

Brahma Sutra [3.2.38] says फलमतः, उपपत्तेः ॥ ३८ ॥ Meaning: From Him (the Lord) are the fruits of actions; for that is reasonable. Discussion: Having described the nature of Brahman, the author proceeds now to discuss the view of the Mimamsakas, who say that Karma (work) and not Īswara gives the fruits of one’s actions. According to them(?) it is useless to set up an Iswara for this purpose, since Karma itself can give that result at a future time. [Cont..]

Shankara Bhasyam of this Sutra [3.2.38] refutes it and says that from Iswara alone come the fruits of one’s work. Karma is insentient (Jada) and short-lived, and cannot therefore be expected to bestow the fruits of actions at a future time according to one’s deserts. We do not see any insentient thing bestow fruits on those who worship it. Therefore it is only from the Lord, who is worshipped through actions, that their results proceed. [Cont..]

The purpose of this sutra [3.2.38] is to censure Mīmāṃsakas and not vedantins (like us). Mīmāṃsaka says no God is needed and Karma itself will take care. @Karthik , Recall that I mentioned many times that Karma is Jada and in order Law of Karma to function it requires the presence of Brahman i.e. Brahman is Witness. You recall the 'Magnet-Pieces of Iron' analogy. [Cont..]

Please know that your incomplete and shallow reading of Brahma sutra [3.2.38] and arriving at wrong conclusion has caused enough trouble. You did that already by quoting Nimbarka's bhasyam and arrived at wrong conclusion! Now your repeating same for sutra 3.2.38 despite Shankara Bhasyam. By reading just one or two sentences, you jump the gun! Please avoid that.

Okay sir  Please accept my apologies . I got what you said. I am new and still learning. I might have erred by arriving at wrong conclusion due to incomplete knowledge. Apologize for that. I understand what you explained. Thanks for your explanation.

I just have one small question. It's related to Law of Karma only . Can I please ask here or do I need to a create a seperate question for it ? It's related to a law of karma only but slightly different. Please do let me know if i may ask here?

No problem, @Karthik , as long as your comments are confined within this post, its fine. Asking unrelated question will cause confusion in the minds of readers.

Please move your latest comments to a new post. This is unrelated to this post. Thanks.

I have removed them and created new post for this. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61626/can-we-infer-law-of-karma-designed-by-godishvara-based-on-bhagavad-gita-chapte Please kindly answer this post sir. Thank you

Thanks @Karthik, I will do.

Namaste sir, can u pls answer this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61626/can-we-infer-law-of-karma-designed-by-godishvara-based-on-bhagavad-gita-chapte Many thanks

Did you remove the post corresponding to the link, @Karthik? In fact, I almost completed the answer to your question consulting based on all three acharayas BG's Bhasyam and it is gone now! Never Mind. Good Luck!

@Marmayogi Apologies . I had deleted because I wanted to reframe my question. My context was little different . I have undeleted it now sir. Please do post your answer. It might be helpful for other users . I have undeleted and updated the post

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61668/does-god-absolutely-not-intervene-at-all @Marmayogi Namaste sir . I request you if you can please kindly answer this question. Will be very greatful to you. Thanks

Thanks for recreating the post. You are most welcome @Karthi . I will answer. Good Luck!

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61668/does-god-absolutely-not-intervene-at-all please kindly answer this and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61670/is-manu-creator-of-law-of-karma-and-all-the-laws

Please answer both of these sir

O.K.  I am busy on something else.  I will be back. Thanks for the understanding.

Okay sure sir . Please kindly answer these 3 questions once you are back.  I have this one more question I wanted to ask. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61678/what-will-happen-if-two-universal-laws-are-conflicting-with-each-other.

Also, just a small question. ये यथा मां प्रपद्यन्ते तांस्तथैव भजाम्यहम् | मम वर्त्मानुवर्तन्ते मनुष्या: पार्थ सर्वश: || 11|| kedhna says "BG 4.11: In whatever way people surrender unto Me, I reciprocate accordingly. Everyone follows My path, knowingly or unknowingly, O son of Pritha." Is it false ? Because u said god doesn't intervene at all? If not intervene atleast will God(Ishvara ) show his divine grace and protect his devotees or not as per this slokam ??

You again jumped the gun with incomplete and shallow reading by missing the commentary section for that sloka! The commentary says: Here, Lord Krishna states that he reciprocates with everyone as they surrender to him. For those who deny the existence of God, he [Lord Krishna] meets them in the form of the law of karma -he sits inside their hearts, notes their actions, and dispenses the results. [Cont...]

Katha Upanishad says योनिमन्ये प्रपद्यन्ते शरीरत्वाय देहिनः । स्थाणुमन्येऽनुसंयन्ति यथाकर्म यथाश्रुतम् ॥ २.२.७ ॥ Meaning: Some jivas [देहिनः/dehinah] go into wombs to be embodied; others pass into the immoveable, according to their karma and to their knowledge.  Please note that Kathopanishad belongs to school of the Krishna Yajurveda. Now, you decide yourself Who has higher priority, Vedha or Bhagavat Geeta? Even God can't override Vedas! I hope you will never raise this issue again and again! Good Luck!

Thanks for your answer. I apologise for raising query again. I just wanted to clarify sir . Sorry if I bothered you in any way. Thanks

Just a small question. As per this slokam in Kathopanishad, it's mentioned यथाकर्म यथाश्रुतम् (as per karma and as per the knowledge) does it mean based on their Karma they get a suitable womb?  It's mentioned some go to womb some go to immovable . My question is even in wombs there are many species animals and humans(Mammals) . So what type of womb they go also depends on their karma ? Is this the meaning from this slokam 2.2.7 From Kathopanishad??

"Krishna sits inside their hearts, notes their actions, and dispenses the results" means Law of karma works in the presence of God and God is witness. I have been driving this point all along, and if it is not acceptable to you then it is up to you and let us not discuss any more. The contents in the link you showed are interpreted according to Gaudiya Sampradaya. So I just set aside without passing any comments. [Cont...]
