Can we infer Law Of Karma designed by God(Ishvara) based on Bhagavad Gita Chapter 16 verses 19-20?
In Bhagavad Gita chapter 16, BG 16.19-20
Krishna says "I hurl the demonic natured people into demonic wombs again and again ",

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 16, Verse 19-20
तानहं द्विषत: क्रूरान्संसारेषु नराधमान् |  क्षिपाम्यजस्रमशुभानासुरीष्वेव योनिषु ||
19|| आसुरीं योनिमापन्ना मूढा  जन्मनि जन्मनि | मामप्राप्यैव कौन्तेय ततो
यान्त्यधमां गतिम् || 20||
These cruel and hateful persons, the vile and vicious of humankind, I
constantly hurl into the wombs of those  with similar demoniac natures
in the cycle of rebirth in the material  world. These ignorant souls
take birth again and again in demoniac  wombs. Failing to reach Me, O
Arjun, they gradually sink to the most  abominable type of existence.

If we take it in literal sense that means Lord Krishna is only deciding the next birth of such demonic people by putting them into lower Yonis again and again.
That may not be completely true because God doesn't intervene as there is Law of karma already in place
When Krishna says "I hurl them", there can be two inferences

Either krishna himself takes the decision of punarjanma and makes demonic people born in demonic wombs as Krishna says "I hurl them"

When he says "I hurl them" it could mean Krishna has made this law of karma in such a way that it works as his will (in this case his will is demonic people getting into demonic wombs) ?..


As Krishna directly does not intervene and as law of Karma is already in place, so can Point 2 be correct inference?
So if point 2 is correct, could it be possible that krisna has created the law of karma to work as per his will?

Karma is by default in the nature of existence, no one created it  ; as you want to know how , then learn about nirmanakaya
(the materialization-dematerialization of the whole existence including self also as part of whole )

Memory is karma and Memory is Solid including the Semi- Solid  as non- nothing tatvas , which moves in direction by nothing and this individual nothing is as self ahamkara (it only means making of self/i ) , and this identification out of this infinite prakrit Makes self .

-this self tries to acquire more and Enjoy more ;thus doing karma in world'
There is no cause and Effect in karma ,only Samskara which means anybody wants something then the cream will be left on him '
As - Anybody wants to give poison to anybody then , There are two options one he can give himself ,or he can give with a third person not by himself,
In both cases the poison eventually comes to himself or first he himself touches the poison , which only thing he can remember makes him around his whole life around poison, because the nature of nothing and existence, any long -term focus sticks the cream of that focus of the object .
As Thirsty man can always be found around water , during living and after death .
Thus self himself is eating karma or Samskara or fruits
just remember there is no cause and effect, at a moment only linear focus is there.
In Truth there is 0 Karma and infinite karma , it depends on self, sometimes one bear others karma because,he wants that ,that other also want mean
If a person sits and does nothing but wants exactly what the other criminal wants ,then there is a possibility, somehow that person bears karma without doing anything.
"'we are Ocean '"
if you know more, then read my poems on Instagram - poetlly.

The post has a link and let us reproduce same: Bhagavat Gīta [Chapter-16, Slokas: 19-20] and the following are the contents including the comments section:

तानहं द्विषत: क्रूरान्संसारेषु नराधमान् |
क्षिपाम्यजस्रमशुभानासुरीष्वेव योनिषु || १९ ||
आसुरीं योनिमापन्ना मूढा जन्मनि जन्मनि |
मामप्राप्यैव कौन्तेय ततो यान्त्यधमां गतिम् || २० ||

Meaning: These cruel and hateful persons, the vile and vicious of humankind, I
constantly hurl into the wombs of those with similar demoniac natures
in the cycle of rebirth in the material world. These ignorant souls
take birth again and again in demoniac wombs. Failing to reach Me, O
Arjun, they gradually sink to the most abominable type of existence. ||
19-20 ||
Commentary: Shree Krishna once again describes the repercussions of the demoniac mentality. He says that in their next lives, he gives
them birth in families with similar mentalities, where they get a
suitable demoniac environment to exercise their free will and heartily
vent their degraded nature. From this verse, we can also infer that it
is not in the soul’s hands to choose the species, abode, and
environment of its next birth. God makes this decision according to
the nature and karma of the individual. Thus, the demoniac are sent
into lower and degraded wombs, even to the level of snakes, lizards,
and scorpions, which are receptacles for the evil-minded

Your question If we take it in literal sense that means Lord Krishna is only deciding the next birth of such demonic people by putting them into lower Yonis again and again......So if point 2 is correct, could it be possible that krisna has created the law of karma to work as per his will?
It is crystal clear from contents of commentary section that Lord Krishna makes this decision according to the nature and karma of the individual which implies that He neither interfere nor use His free will.

This also implies that Law of Karma works under the presence of God
who is Witness.

Good Luck!
.
