Does God absolutely not intervene at all?
Namasthe
In this slokam Krishna says I personally take the responsibility and take care of my purest of the purest cream of devotees who always meditate and think about me

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 9, Verse 22
अनन्याश्चिन्तयन्तो मां ये जना: पर्युपासते | तेषां नित्याभियुक्तानां योगक्षेमं वहाम्यहम् || 22||
BG 9.22: There are those who always think of Me and engage in
exclusive devotion to Me. To them, whose minds are always absorbed in
Me, I provide what they lack and preserve what they already possess.

And in BG 4.11 , Lord Krishna says

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 4, Verse 11
ये यथा मां प्रपद्यन्ते तांस्तथैव भजाम्यहम् | मम वर्त्मानुवर्तन्ते मनुष्या: पार्थ सर्वश: || 11||
BG 4.11: In whatever way people surrender unto Me, I reciprocate
accordingly. Everyone follows My path, knowingly or unknowingly, O son
of Pritha.

Are both of them authentic and functional?
Because God is just a witness as per Svetasvathara upanishad 6.11 and absolutely doesn't intervene
I have one more question related to it.
Let us suppose there is a good human being who is involved in doing good karma (punya) all life and a devotee of God
Let us assume hypothetical situation where due to some unknown reason a situation came where he is going to perish and rot in lower Yonis for eternity and never get human birth
Note :- I am aware this does not happen in reality. This is purely a hypothetical question. Please kindly don't question it. My sole intention of asking this question is if in case such a situation comes will god protect or not in such case
As per Law of karma, even if we take all the millions of past lives into consideration this is not possible because even after crores of births in lower Yonis when most of bad karma is burnt up and when remaining good karma sprouts up in prarabhda (karmasaya), he has to get a human birth
So this situation is against the law of karma .
So due to xyz reason such as conflict of other laws, such as someone cursed him or someone did black magic on him or someone put a promise to God that if I break it, this person will rot in lower yoni for eternity and broke it
Let us assume due to xyz unknown reason.
I repeat again this is hypothetical situation. Please kindly assume it  without questioning for this scenario POV.
So suppose there came a situation where he is supposed to rot in lower Yonis for eternity never get human birth even though he doesn't deserve it and it's against law of karma
In such a case, Injustice (Anyayam) is happening which is against the Cosmic order and principles of Dharma .
So in such case will God intervene and save such a person from this tremendously huge punishment which he doesn't deserve?
Or just keep watching and allow it happen saying god is just a witness?
Please kindly answer this question
And I repeat again This is a hypothetical situation, that's why I mentioned due to unknown XYZ reason. My question is assume suppose such a situation arises will god save him or not provided he has not done such huge bad karma to deserve it ?
Please kindly answer me. I am personally facing a serious issue related to this. I will be very greatful if anyone can answer me with proper quotes from Scriptures.
Thanks
