Is Manu creator of Law of Karma and all the Laws?
In Srimad Bhagavatham, it's mentioned in ŚB 7.8.48

ŚB 7.8.48.
श्रीमनव ऊचु: मनवो वयं तव निदेशकारिणो दितिजेन देव परिभूतसेतव: । भवता खल: स उपसंहृत: प्रभो करवाम ते किमनुशाधि किङ्करान् ॥ ४८ ॥
All the Manus offered their prayers as follows: As Your order
carriers, O Lord, we, the Manus, are the law-givers for human society,
but because of the temporary supremacy of this great demon,
Hiraṇyakaśipu, our laws for maintaining varṇāśrama-dharma were
destroyed. O Lord, now that You have killed this great demon, we are
in our normal condition. Kindly order us, Your eternal servants, what
to do now.

As per this, Manu is the law giver.
Does it mean Manu created all the Laws of this Universe such as Law Of Karma?
